# Unknown word (CssSyntaxError)stylelint(CssSyntaxError)

Tags: reactjs, frontend, syntax-error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPcse.png)

I was working on the frontend to build a React app. Then I added the backend file. I simply wanted to connect the frontend to the backend, and now I see this error on every page. How can I solve this? If anyone knows, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.